# sync gradle error when trying room java android studio

Tags: java, android, android-studio, gradle, android-room

how to solve gradle error when doing sync?

it shows :
A problem occurred evaluating project ':app'.

> Could not get unknown property 'appCompatVersion' for root project 'RoomWordSample' of type org.gradle.api.Project.

Comment: Without a bit of information on what you are gradling or synching to or from it is impossible to help you with errors. Please provide all the info (but also only JUST the info/code/settings etc.. ) needed to reproduce the issue.

Comment: Please edit your question to include the build.gradle files for both your root project and app.

Answer (score 1):

Just add a property to project level `build.gradle` file.  I am posting my project level build.gradle file because you can map it to your one. Just look at bottom of posted code. Project level `build.gradle` file looks Like :

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.4.30'
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.1.2'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
        jcenter()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
// Here property is added which can be accessed inside :app level build.gradle file
ext {
    appCompatVersion = '1.2.0'
}
```